# Convert for loop to recursive function in python3

Tags: python, recursion

Is it possible to convert the following loop:

```
c = 0
for a in find:
    c += 1
return c
```

Where find is a list like `[a,b,c,d]` to a function that uses recursion **without using external libraries**?

Comment: You need specifically `a` to be in the list? Or just `some element` in list?

Comment: just some element in list, I managed to do it!

Comment: It's strange to me that "without using external libraries" is emphasized here. This is a question of fundamental programming technique, and it seems very unlikely that any library would be helpful.

Comment: It is now more than clear to me. I was still a novice, now a PhD student in CS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count(ls):
    if not ls:  # empty
        return 0
    return count(ls[1:]) + 1
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> find = [a, b, c, d]
>>> count(find)
4
```

Comment: You should change to `return count(ls[1:]) + 1`, otherwise you'll get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. I didn't DV btw.

Comment: Yep, sorry, oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so by defining the following function:

```
def ric(find, n, c):    
    if n < len(find):
        if find[n] in find:
            c += 1
        n += 1
        return ric(find, n, c)
    else:
        return c
```

and calling it with `ric(find, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this would work:

```
def to_rec(lst):
    # base case, when list is empty
    if not lst:
        return 0

    # recursive case
    return 1 + to_rec(lst[1:])
```

**Base case:** If the list has no elements, return `0`.

**Recursive case:** Otherwise return 1 + the length of the list, minus one element, which is why we use `[1:]` here, to disregard the head of the list.

You could also explicitly set an accumulator with a helper function. If you've ever used a functional programming language, such as Haskell or Prolog, this technique is quite popular. Here is what it could look like:

```
# main function
def to_rec(lst):

    # calls helper function with starting accumulator of 0
    return accum(lst, 0)

def accum(lst, acc):

    # returns accumulator instead
    if not lst:
        return acc

    # increments accumulator, and looks at the tail of the list
    return accum(lst[1:], acc + 1)
```

Both work as follows:

```
>>> print(to_rec(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
4
>>> print(to_rec([]))
0
>>> print(to_rec(['a']))
1
```